# Stagemonitor: In browser widget enabled for standalone

Tags: performance, stagemonitor

I am trying stagemonitor with standalone applicaion. And i get metrics for jmx reporter correctly. I want to get that in browser-widget. I saw config `stagemonitor.web.widget.enabled = true` will enable this. But how to get dashbord. Do we have to use grafana for this ?